# Python tool that automatically converts between snake case and camel case?

Tags: software-development, python, programming

I have problems typing a lot of underscores because it's uncomfortable for my wrists and it risks a repetitive strain injury over time.

I would prefer to use Java-style camelcase everywhere - it's more ergonomic. Unfortunately the vast majority of Python libraries use underscores.

So I would like a tool or an IDE that auto-translates between camel case and underscores (sometimes called "snake case"). The tool has to be able to auto-convert references to objects of a given type (for example, a command could be: "Convert all function arguments from snake case to camel case" or "Convert all variables from camel case to snake case").

I'd prefer an IDE or a GUI tool, however command line tools are also acceptable. The best solution would be an IDE where I can set what types of objects should be camel case or snake case, type in either case, and have the IDE automatically recognize them in real-time and fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something that works. This solution works best on Mac OS and probably Linux.

- (Mac OS only) Go into System Preferences -> Keyboard, Shortcuts tab; click on Spotlight in the left menu list and disable "Show spotlight search" on the right menu list after that
- Download the PyCharm IDE (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)
- In Pycharm, open any file for writing, or a blank file.
- Pycharm: Edit menu -> Macros -> Start Macro Recording
- Type an underscore in the file.
- Edit menu -> Macros -> Stop Macro Recording
- Name the macro "underscore" or something similar
- PyCharm menu -> Preferences -> Keymap, scroll down to Macros
- Double click on the underscore macro, click "Add Keyboard Shortcut"
- Record Command+Space as the shortcut. For reference, the command button is the same as the Windows button (if you're using a non-Apple external keyboard).

You can now ergonomically type underscores with either hand. On Windows, you might use Shift+Space or Control+Space, although I haven't tested those.